# NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-api

I've just installed Devise in a rails-api application. I've added the following to my ApplicationController:

```
include AbstractController::Layouts
include ActionController::MimeResponds
include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic::ControllerMethods
include ActionController::MimeResponds 
include ActionController::Cookies
```

And I've added this to my config/application.rb:

```
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
```

When I try to access `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in` (protected by Devise) I'm seeing the error:

**NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#new**
undefined method `permit' for {}:Hash

The trace points to here:

```
devise (3.1.1) lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb:50:in `sign_in'
```

Not sure what I need to include for Devise to know what/where this 'permit' method is.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Too me it seem like you have to add `strong_parameter` gem as well since your are using `rails_api` since devise 3.1.1 is meant for rails 4 by default and strong parameter is added in rails 4 by default